xltabular long table with repeating footnotes on every occuring page
I am using a xltabular environment for my long table. In some cell I am reusing the same footnotes (with footref from scrextend).
I would like to repeat the footnotes on every page where the footnote is referenced inside the table. How is that possible?
In the example below, the footnote should also go at the end of page 2.
Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} % table formatting
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrextend} %footnotes with same referecne
\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}


%% document
\begin{document}

    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ l X }
        \toprule
        \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Description} \\
        \toprule
        \endfirsthead
        \toprule
        \textbf{No.} & \textbf{Description} \\
        \toprule
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        1 & \lipsum[1-2]\footnote{\label{my_footnote}Some footnote that is being reused}\\
        2 & \lipsum[1-2]\\
        3 & \lipsum[1-2]\footref{my_footnote}\\
    \end{xltabular}


\end{document}





Welcome to TeX.SE.
